# Getting data from multiple databases with same tablenames in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I need to get data from different imported MySQL-databases in Django 
*(Django 1.11.7, Python 3.5.2)*.
I run `manage.py inspectdb --database '<db>'` and then use the models in django.

Until now, I only had to access tables with different names. For this purpose, I used the `using` keyword in the queryset to specify the appropriate database and then concatenated the result, like this:

```
from ..models.db1 import Members
from ..models.db2 import Actor

context['db1_data'] = Members.objects.using('db1').filter...
context['db2_data'] = Actor.objects.using('db1').filter...

context["member_list"] = list(chain(
    context["db1_data"],
    context["db2_data"],
))

return context
```

Now I have the problem that there are tables with the same model names in two databases. I get the following error when using the above-mentioned method (I substituted the names):

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting '<table-name>' models in application '<app>': <class '<app>.<subfolder>.models.<db1>.<table-name>'> and <class '<app>.<subfolder>.models.<db2>.<table-name>'>.
```

I already tried importing the model with a different name, like this:

```
from ..models.db3 import Members as OtherMembers
```

but the error still comes up.

Shouldn't `from ..models.db1` and `from ..models.db2` be clear enough for Django to spot the difference between the two models?

One option would probably be to rename the models themselves, but that would mean to rename every database model with the same names. Since I will use many more databases in the future, this is not an option for me.

I tried `from models import db1, db2` and then `db1.Members` etc., which still raises the error.

I read about the meta `db_table = 'dbname.tablename'`-option, but since the model is auto-generated through `inspectdb`, it already has something like this on every class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    <models>

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_model'
```

As described before, the other database has the exact same model and hence the same Meta classes. I can't and don't want to change every Meta class.

---

**EDIT:**

My project structure looks like this:

```
app
    -> admin.py
    -> ...
    -> models.py
    -> views.py
    subfolder
        -> models
            -> db1.py
            -> db2.py
        -> views
            -> db1.py
            -> db2.py
```

Comment: I think the problem is, you defined two model classes with same name. You can use same modesl for any database(if both are same). Its perfectly works for me.

Comment: >>> chain(Build.objects.using('ob').all(), Build.objects.using('sb').all())
<itertools.chain object at 0x92e834c>

Comment: How did you import your models then? If I run `from .models.db1 import Members` and `from .models.db2 import Members` from the shell, I get the error I described above.

Comment: Are all tables going to be unmanaged? Are the tables from both DB imported into a single app? Did you set up both database connections in your `settings.py`?

Comment: yes currently we are managing tables with sql files. all models sitting in one file.

Comment: yes i have DATABASES dict of database details

Comment: @cezar All the tables are imported into a single app. The connections work just fine; as I said, getting data from them without the same table names is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have set up your [multiple databases correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases):

1. Have you tried to add a [Custom Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)? 
   If not follow the example given on the documentation link.
2. Have you tried to use a [Custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) for your models?

   Create a manager for each model, like this:

   ```
   class YourModelManagerX(models.Manager):
       def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
           return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).using('your_db_X')
   ```

   And then add it to your appropriate model as the `objects` field:

   ```
   class YourModel(models.Model):
       ...
       fields
       ...
       objects = YourManagerX()

       class Meta:
           managed = False
   ```

You may need to try both at once.

Comment: @sqe Good to know! Happy holidays :)

Answer (score 1):

If db1.Members and db3.Members have the same definition, you do not have to redeclare the Members class separately for each database.

Models.py

```
...
class Members(models.Model): # Only declared once ever!
    ....
```

then,

```
from Models import Members

context['db1_data'] = Members.objects.using('db1').filter...
context['db3_data'] = Members.objects.using('db3').filter...

... # continue processing
```

> Shouldn't from ..models.db1 and from ..models.db2 be clear enough for django to spot the difference between the two models?

Django Models are not database-specific, more like schema-specific, so if you have the same table in two different databases, one class extending `model.Models` suffices. Then, when you attempt to retrieve the objects, either specify the database with `using()`, or using routers, which you can read about in the Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

Comment: Well, as I said, this is what I already did. I edited my question in order to show my app structure. The `class Members` exists in `models.db1` and `models.db2` as well. I can't just `from ..models import Members` because of my file structure (produces a `ImportError: cannot import name 'Members'`). I'm already using the `context['db1_data'] = Members.objects.using('db1').filter...` syntax. Still the same error.

Comment: You do not have to redefine the `Members` class in `models.py`, `subfolder/models/db1.py`, and `subfolder/models/db1.py` as well. There are no differences in their definition right? Just define them once in the top level `models.py` file, then wherever you want to access `Members` objects, regardless of which database you want to import them from, `from models import Members` to import from that top-level `models.py`

Comment: I tried defining them in my `models.py` file and importing the way you described, but unfortunately it throws the same error. However, this can't be the solution on the long run since the `Members` model is just one out of many models that are same and I'd like to access. Isn't it possible to have multiple model-files with same classes in subfolders and to access them with a syntax like `<folder>.<file>.<model>`?